# Princess Elizabeth's Space Marines game league?

Tags: history-of-gaming, product-identification, rpg-pop-culture

Does anyone have any information about the game league described in [this post on Reddit's r/DungeonsAndDragons](https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonsAndDragons/comments/gpgo6i/am_i_crazy_or_does_this_styrofoam_packing_insert/frluqo2/)?

> Back in the early 2000s, a coworker used to be involved in a game league that used [styrofoam packing inserts as dungeons]. It was called something like "Princess Elizabeth's Space Marines". It was not Warhammer, it was some ad hoc wargaming thing that people were playing in the mid atlantic and northeastern US during that time. I have never been able to find documentation about it and I might be misremembering the name, but they primarily used these as their dungeons. Now I'm going to go into a google rabbit hole looking for this for hours. I never got to play but he had tons of pics of the games they played.

Comment: I undid that edit because I feel that edit misrepresents my original question. We know *now* that it is a published game, but the original quoted post described it as a game league, and I was indeed originally asking about the game league.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest editing the question to ask about the gaming league that you thought was called by that name, and then edit the answer to indicate that it's the RPG and not any specific gaming league that was called by that name.

Comment: Okay, edited answer to indicate it turned out to be a game rather than a game league.

Comment: Looks good now! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After I posted this question, a [response was posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonsAndDragons/comments/gpgo6i/am_i_crazy_or_does_this_styrofoam_packing_insert/frm4bwf/) identifying the subject of the quoted post as not a game league, but instead a miniatures game from 1986 called *Princess Ryan's Space Marines: Squad Combat in the 23rd Century*.

Avalon Hill published a sequel called *Princess Ryan's Star Marines* in 1997.

BoardGameGeek has more information about both [the original game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24814/princess-ryans-space-marines-squad-combat-23rd-cen) and [the sequel](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/127/princess-ryans-star-marines).